# PhpStorm and Xdebug not working

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

> SOLVED

All day long I have tried different methods and techniques to make **xdebug** working. I have installed the plugin into Chrome, I've made the bookmarks for creating cookies...

The validator seems alright but when I try refreshing Chrome with breakpoints nothing happens. It's like the connection is not made, skipping my breakpoints.

I'm trying to made it work with PHP 5.6

[image]

I am using MAMP and the latest PhpStorm 2018.1

[image]

My server : 
[image]

My `phpinfo()` xdebug category :
[image]

My php.ini
[image]

XDEBUG LOG :
[image]

> To solve this issue i've place an absolute path on my server
>   [image]

Thanks.

Comment: **1)** *"My phpinfo() xdebug category"* Useless ... unless you will show WHOLE xdebug section and not just the header. This particular part (shown on screenshot) has very little value -- it only confirms that xdebug is installed and its' version. But shows no actual settings (which can be different from php.ini, e.g. when editing wrong .ini file etc) **2)** Collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful session/debug attempt and share it -- it may provide a lot of hints. https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log . The rest -- based on answers to these two.

Comment: Do you use php-fpm? It runs on the same port as xdebug, 9000. I had to change one of them to debug :)

Comment: **3)** Default xdebug port (TCP 9000) may already be occupied by php-fpm. You are on Mac ... so there is a decent chance that you have it installed (even if you do not remember installing that). Changing pot to 9001 in both php.ini and PhpStorm settings may help in instant. As mentioned earlier -- Xdebug log may give such hints in his response (if you know how to read it).

Comment: I am not using php-fpm but i have tried to made it working by changing the port but without luck.

Comment: Xdebug log is empty, inside php.ini i've place "xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log" but in that path the file is empty. I will edit with full xdebug category image

Comment: If log is empty .. then maybe xdebug does not see the "debug me" flag (cookie/request parameter). Put `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` -- any difference? In general (in case if you have not seen it yet): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: I've tried. The issue is still there..

Comment: If there is no log .. then something else is missing. Because with remote_autostart=1 it should be generated for each script run. Try restarting whole system -- may help.

Comment: I've manage to make the log working.

Comment: Does i have any change to not use the absolute path on every project?

Comment: @CarabusAlexandru I do not see any difference between project path and Absolute path (as you have called it). If there is no difference then simply disable the checkbox so they are not used at all. It's only needed for remote debug (when paths are most likely different) or when symbolic links are used.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me: I opened Workspace.xml in my .idea-folder and removed everything that had to do with xdebug.